# How to include external css file of a shiny app into flexdashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, flexdashboard

How can I include a external css of a shiny app into the flexdashboard.  I have tried putting css file in the YAML header but that didn't work

The **style.css** is inside www directory

**style.css**

````
```
p{
  
  font-size:100px
}
```
````

**dashboard.rmd**

````
```
---
title: 'Dashboard Like a Boss'
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
    orientation: rows
    runtime: shiny
    css: style.css
---

```{r}
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "style.css")),
  tags$p("Hello, world!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)

```
````

In the dashboard, the styling doesn't work, but when the shiny app is run in a separate file (e.g., app.R), the styling works.

Output of flexdasboard:

[image]

Output of app.R

[image]

Comment: It worked for me when I ran your code.

Comment: If it's in the "www" directory then I would assume you should use that path. e.g. `css: "www/style.css"`

Comment: @Jamie I tried it but gives me Hello World without the style. Do I need make changes on the 'ui' of shiny app in markdown

Comment: @ViviG Did it work in the markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to use styling for the Shiny App inside flexdashboard.
By defining a  variable (css in this case) and using **tags$style(HTML(css))** within the UI section, you can apply custom styles to the elements in your Shiny App

```
css <- '
p{
  font-size:100px;
}
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  tags$p("Hello, world!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now when I run the document the the flexdashboard display with the style. Even though this won't be the best approach but works for now.
Other answers are also welcome